# How to empty string for custom checkout field?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

In WooCommerce, I have tried to get an empty value for custom checkout field with:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_get_value','__return_empty_string', 1, 1);
```

However, it deletes all fields on load.

I just want to empty only `['billing']['billing_type']`

By the way, it's a radio field.

Comment: I'm not familiar with woocommerce_checkout_get_value, but can you access $_GET or $_POST or $_REQUEST directly?  If so, would you consider doing unset($_REQUEST['billing']['billing_type']); ?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Comment: Thank you but unset is not actually what I want, because it completely destroys field. When customer goes in checkout he/she 'll see all details of last order. But I want to reselect billing_type. Another alternative solution is to delete radio button's default selected value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As it's a radio button custom checkout field, you should provide the necessary code to test it.

The correct code using a custom function hooked in `woocommerce_checkout_get_value` filter hook, to get an empty value for any desired checkout field is:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_get_value','custom_checkout_get_value', 10, 2);
function custom_checkout_get_value( $value, $imput ){
    if($imput == 'billing_type')
        $value = '';
    return $value;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works in WC 3+ with other billing fields like `'billing_phone'` …